# Is a morphism $f:A\rightarrow B$ uniquely determined by the compositions $f\circ g$ for all $g:T\rightarrow A$?

Tags: category-theory, group-schemes

Im asking in general but to give a little context, i'm studying group schemes and have been trying to prove that the composition morphism $m:G\times G \rightarrow G$ is uniquely determined by the composition law $f\cdot g = m\circ (f\times g)$ for all $f,g:T\rightarrow G$.

My only guess is that indeed $m$ is unique because of its value on all pairs $(f,g)$.

Comment: What is $T$ here? An arbitrary object, the terminal object, or something else?

Comment: A useless answer is that this is true by Yoneda, and concretely one just takes $T=A$ and $g=1_A$. But if you mean to fix $T$ then this does not work and will be generally false for a general category. I don't know the specific context here but I suspect that yes, since you have a point-set you can appeal to, this should be true. But morphisms of schemes involve data on the sheaves as well, so maybe (I don't know) the structural morphisms between sheaves are not uniquely determined

Comment: You may need to be more precise about the setting here but it seems you look at enriched categories. However it is odd that you have $G \times G$, what is $G$?

Comment: @varkor $T$ is an arbitrary object

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace Im asking whether it is true for any category, though the specific context im working on is that of a category $\mathcal{C}$ with finite products in which the sets $G(T) = Hom(T,G)$ are magmas with the law of composition $fg = m\circ (f\times g)$, but i don't think that changes the setting substantially.

Comment: So here $m$ would be the colimit of a $\mathcal{C}/G \times G$-diagram ?

Comment: @FShrike You're right. It was actually that simple. However the answer below is nice for its generality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your category $\mathcal{C}$ has finite products and is locally small since you have a magma structure on your Hom-spaces.

For this proof, I **need the functoriality of the composition law**, namely for $h:T' \to T$, $(f \circ h)\cdot (g\circ h) = (f\cdot g) \circ h$.

Consider the representable presheaf $G(-) = \hom(-,G) = h_G$. The Yoneda embedding is define to be the functor
$$\begin{array}{rrcl}
h: &\mathcal{C} &\to &\hat{\mathcal{C}} \\
&X&\mapsto&h_X
\end{array}$$
where $\hat{\mathcal{C}}$ is the category of presheaves over $\mathcal{C}$. You can find in the literature that $h$ is fully faithfull, but for it to be essentially surjective, you need to have a small category (hopefully we don't need it here).

We are looking to find $m \in \hom(G \times G,G)$ and all we know is the presheaf morphism between the two representables (so a natural transformation) $\phi: \hom(-,G \times G) \to \hom(-,G)$ defined by
$$\forall T \in \mathcal{C}, \quad \begin{array}{rrcl}
\phi_T: &\hom(T,G \times G) &\to &\hom(T,G) \\
&(f,g)&\mapsto&f\cdot g
\end{array}$$
This is where we **need the functoriality of the composition law** (otherwise this would not be a natural transformation).

But $\phi \in \hom_\hat{\mathcal{C}}(h_{G \times G},h_G)$ which is isomorphic to $\hom_\mathcal{C} (G \times G, G)$ via $n \mapsto n_*$. Hence there exists a unique $m: G \times G \to G$ such that $m_* = \phi$, which gives you the desired morphism.

Now for any other morphism $m'$, you can check that $m_ = m_*'$ hence by faithfulness, $m=m'$.

Comment: You're right, functoriality of composition is important. I had used it to find a candidate for $m$, given by $P_1 \cdot P_2$, where $P_1,P_2:G\times G \rightarrow G$ are the canonical projections. One can check that $f\cdot g = P_1 \circ (f\times g) \cdot  P_2 \circ (f\times g) = (P_1 \cdot P_2) \circ (f\times g)$. My question was whether this was the only possible $m$, but I think I get it from your answer.

Comment: Looking at the comment by @FShrike it seems that I can indeed determine $m$ explicitly by taking $T=G\times G = A$ and $g = Id_A$, since $T$ can be taken to be anything in the case I was referring to. However your answer is very helpful for looking at a more general case.

Comment: Yes of course, in fact if you explicit the inverse isomorphism, it gives you $m_*(1_a)$ but it is useful to get a Hang of the yoneda Lemma for less trivial cases